# Earliest source for teaching Torah in secret to hide from the Romans

Tags: sources-mekorot, torah-study, midrash

A number of online sources (such as [this article](https://www.torahmusings.com/2010/04/lag-baomer-bows-arrows/) by Rabbi Ari Enkin, or [this article](https://www.theyeshivaworld.com/news/headlines-breaking-stories/1275112/bows-arrows-lag-baomer.html) by Rabbi Yair Hoffman) mention the tradition that rabbonim used to go out into the woods and teach Torah while *pretending* to do something that the Romans considered innocuous (like playing with bows and arrows).

So far, I have yet to find an article that mentions a source for this claim.

What is the earliest source that rabbonim used to teach Torah in secret, out in the woods, using a ruse of this nature?

Comment: Is it specific to Romans of the Greeks also?

Comment: Keep in mind that they had no books (or computers) to study Torah, they could do it really anywhere - that wasn't so hard as it seems. That's why our forefathers had no problem of studying Torah while shepherding.

Comment: The opposite is said about Rabbi Akiva שהיה מקהיל קהלות ברבים ועוסק בתורה ([Berachot 61b](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%A1%D7%90_%D7%91))

Comment: @AlBerko More like we rely too heavily on our books, but they knew Torah orally and therefore didn’t need them. They had scrolls at least.

Comment: @DonielF One of our hypes. They knew Tanach and some Mishnayos (each one knew a different set - whatever he got from his Rabbis), but that's it - nothing to compare to our printed (and electronic) world.

Comment: @AlBerko I don’t disagree, but my point still remains - they had memorized at least what they knew, and they could take it anywhere. We, for the most part, aren’t doing that because we have a crutch in the form of Sefaria, etc.

Comment: @DonielF My point is that this wasn't something outstanding - to seclude for Torah learning. There's no obligation to learn Torah in town (BTW Batey Midrash were mostly out of town, DKY) so it's nothing special to write home about.

Comment: Your question is a fraud (or I don't understand what you ask) - the article clearly states that it was Bnei Issachar circa 1800 that brought this vague explanation and connection to bows and arrows. You neglect it and refer to "*mention the tradition*". There was no tradition as B"I says and you have to state it in your question. Then there's no question left.

Comment: practicing bows and arrows in the wood would be considered a preparation for a revolt and everybody would be executed. There was no such tradition.

Comment: @AlBerko I don't know what that means for my question to be "a fraud". Are you accusing me of asking it insincerely? If the Bnei Yissaschar says this, that sounds like an answer to me, and if you can source the BY you should share it. Rav Miller's article credits the BY with the first of two explanations only; the second (that it relates to a ruse) is unsourced. Maybe it's badly written and both explanations are in the BY. As for your comment that there was no such tradition, well, you're obviously wrong. I've shown you two sources that there was. "I've never heard of it" is not a source.

Comment: I'm trying to help you here, sorry for being rude. the articles you cited are not "sources", they speculate some theories based on the same BY. So if you read them you should have known that BY is the source, otherwise, they would quote someone earlier. 2. I admit I don't understand the point of the question - is it bows or secrecy? As hiding from Romans is not a novelty, and neither is learning Torah in seclusion (Rashbi?), we have enough testimonies in the Gemmorah, I suppose the question is all about bows or other tricks...

Comment: Would you polish the question to focus on what exactly is the novelty, please?